# Pygame Maze Game not creating levels correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, maze

So I'm trying to create a maze game with levels for a project at school. The code is a bit repetitive sorry I've only just started coding using pygame. When run the program should output a maze that once the user completes moves onto the next level - each level is randomly generated. However, only the first level is showing properly the rest of the levels appear to be a grid- which is making me think that the game is creating a new maze over the old.

I've pasted the code below - feel free to leave any advice on how to improve what I have :)

```
class Maze:

  def __init__(self, rows=30, cols=40):

    self.rows = rows
    self.cols = cols
    self.keep_going = 1

    self.maze = {}
    for y in range(rows):
      for x in range(cols):
        cell = {'south' : 1, 'east' : 1, 'visited': 0}
        self.maze[(x,y)] = cell

  def generate(self, start_cell=None, stack=[])

    if start_cell is None:
      start_cell = self.maze[(self.cols-1, self.rows-1)]

    if not self.keep_going:
      return

    self.check_finished()
    neighbors = []

    # if the stack is empty, add the start cell
    if len(stack) == 0:
      stack.append(start_cell)

    # set current cell to last cell
    curr_cell = stack[-1]

    # get neighbors and shuffle 'em up a bit
    neighbors = self.get_neighbors(curr_cell)
    shuffle(neighbors)

    for neighbor in neighbors:
      if neighbor['visited'] == 0:
        neighbor['visited'] = 1
        stack.append(neighbor)
        self.knock_wall(curr_cell, neighbor)

        self.generate(start_cell, stack)

  def get_coords(self, cell):
    # grabs coords of a given cell
    coords = (-1, -1)
    for k in self.maze:
      if self.maze[k] is cell:
        coords = (k[0], k[1])
        break
    return coords

  def get_neighbors(self, cell):
    # obvious
    neighbors = []

    (x, y) = self.get_coords(cell)
    if (x, y) == (-1, -1):
      return neighbors

    north = (x, y-1)
    south = (x, y+1)
    east = (x+1, y)
    west = (x-1, y)

    if north in self.maze:
      neighbors.append(self.maze[north])
    if south in self.maze:
      neighbors.append(self.maze[south])
    if east in self.maze:
      neighbors.append(self.maze[east])
    if west in self.maze:
      neighbors.append(self.maze[west])

    return neighbors

  def knock_wall(self, cell, neighbor):
    # knocks down wall between cell and neighbor.
    xc, yc = self.get_coords(cell)
    xn, yn = self.get_coords(neighbor)

    # Which neighbor?
    if xc == xn and yc == yn + 1:
      # neighbor's above, knock out south wall of neighbor
      neighbor['south'] = 0
    elif xc == xn and yc == yn - 1:
      # neighbor's below, knock out south wall of cell
      cell['south'] = 0
    elif xc == xn + 1 and yc == yn:
      # neighbor's left, knock out east wall of neighbor
      neighbor['east'] = 0
    elif xc == xn - 1 and yc == yn:
      # neighbor's right, knock down east wall of cell
      cell['east'] = 0

  def check_finished(self):
    # Checks if we're done generating
    done = 1
    for k in self.maze:
      if self.maze[k]['visited'] == 0:
        done = 0
        break
    if done:
      self.keep_going = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] the rest of the levels appear to be a grid- which is making me think that the game is creating a new maze over the old.

The issue is caused by a common mistake in Python.

See [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

> **Important warning:** The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes

In your case the arguments to the method `generate` of class `Maze` has default arguments:

> ```py
> class Maze:
>    # [...]
>
>    def generate(self, start_cell=None, stack=[]):
>        # [...]
> ```

In the method `generate` elements are append to `stack`. The maze is generated trusting in the default argument:

> ```py
> self.maze_obj.generate(self.maze_obj.maze[(0,0)])
> ```

That causes that the 1st generation of the mace succeeds, but the following generation fails, because `stack` contains all the elements of the former generation process.

Pass an empty list to `generate` to solve the issue:

<s>`self.maze_obj.generate(self.maze_obj.maze[(0,0)])`</s>

```py
self.maze_obj.generate(self.maze_obj.maze[(0,0)], [])
```

Or change the default argument to `None`:

```py
class Maze:
    # [...]

    def generate(self, start_cell=None, stack=None):
        if stack == None:
            stack = []
```